# Can I throw my own strict mode violation [on Android]?

Tags: android

I have a helper class that should only ever run in a background thread.  Is there a way I can leverage the StrictMode component and throw my own StrictMode violation if it's run on the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of API 11, it looks like the best option is to use a ThreadPolicy.Builder to [detectCustomSlowCalls()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder.html#detectCustomSlowCalls%28%29).  In the background thread, you can then tag the method as 'slow' by calling [StrictMode.noteSlowCall()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html#noteSlowCall%28java.lang.String%29).

This apparently means that a StrictMode violation will be thrown if the offending method takes too long to execute.

Comment: FWIW, the docs on this are terrible.  ThreadPolicy.Builder has copy/paste errors, and StrictMode.noteSlowCall() never defines what actually qualifies a 'slow' event.

Comment: Also, I learned about this from [Pro Android Apps](http://www.amazon.com/Android-Performance-Optimization-Professional-Apress/dp/1430239999), which has some totally decent tips.

Comment: StrictMode won't log slow method calls for you. That timing needs to be implemented by the application developer and they are responsible for calling noteSlowCall("err msg"); when a section of code is running slow